# Include output of commands in Scapy packet

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix, scapy

I am successfully sending Scapy packets from A to B and having the data printed on the distant end. My current Scapy commands are:

`packet=IP(dst="192.168.0.10")/UDP(sport=50000, dport=1234)/Raw('DATA')`

`send (packet, count=10, inter=3)`

For example's sake, say I want to include the output of `ifconfig` and the output of `date` in my packet which is being sent every 3 seconds.

How can I replace the raw data with the output of those two commands?